# SOLR 4.10.2 - Add field with default value

Tags: solr, solr4

I have a SOLR Core 4.10.2

I want to add a field VehicalType with an index IDX_VehicalType with a default value of "car" for all rows in the core. - I want this field populated with "car"

I have been able to add the field and index successfully using the following in the schema.xml and Reloading the core from from Core Admin:

```
<field name="IDX_VehicleType" type="text_Exact" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="VehicleType" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<copyField source="VehicleType" dest="IDX_VehicleType"/>
```

When I try to give the field a default using the default attribute - and reload, and optimize the core from Core Admin, the field is not populated.

```
<field name="IDX_VehicleType" type="text_Exact" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" default="car"/>
<field name="VehicleType" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" default="car"/>
<copyField source="VehicleType" dest="IDX_VehicleType"/>
```

I see the field in the schema browser, but its not showing up in the results.

Comment: Dis you reindex your documents? Default value is applied at indexation time AFAIK.

Comment: @GaëlJ I went to Core Admin, and chose the core, then clicked on Reload, and then clicked on Optimize (I think optimize reindexes) - is there another reindex command?

Comment: Optimize does not reindex, it optimizes current index. To reindex you have no other choice as re-inserting all documents in Solr from the initial datasource.

Answer (score 0):

This change falls under the category of changes which need reindexing in SOLR to reflect the value in the field.
To repeat, if we want to fill in the field with the default value for existing documents in the index, we would need to reindex all the docs in the index.

And for any future add/updates to the index, the default field value would be auto set by SOLR according to the new schema.

More on this:
https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_0/reindexing.html#changing-field-and-field-type-properties
https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_0/defining-fields.html#field-properties